# Is it possible to load Components from database Using Angular 6 and REST APIs?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, content-management-system, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

Is it possible to load Components from database Using Angular 6 and REST APIs?

I'm trying to write a CMS using these technologies: **C#, ASP.net Core, WebAPI, Angular 6,...**

Comment: It may be a struggle. Angular needs to be transpiled before it can be run. That's not to say you couldn't store HTML and load that, but I don't think you'd be able to store any Angular template syntax

Comment: You could use lazy loading: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

Using normal means, Angular can't load a component that's not known at compile-time.
Usually, this means that the component is listed in a Module's 'declarations' section.

You can create Components dynamically, but they still need to be known at compile-time, and listed in a module's 'entryComponents' section.

If I understand your desired scenario, lazy-loading modules will not help - that's only meant to improve initial load time, so that on first load, the user doesn't have to wait for all modules in the app to load. You still can't create components that aren't known at compile time.

That said, it is possible to compile components on the fly, but only in 'interpreted' mode, usually referred to as 'development mode'. When using AOT (ahead-of-time compilation), you can't do this. And IMHO, no-one in their right mind would use a non-AOT build in production.

What I have done that is similar to what you want is to create (known at compile time) Components dynamically, based on configuration that I get from a REST call. I have a bunch of components that are AOT-compiled, and a map that associates strings with components. The components are customizable with a configuration object. Given a config from the REST call, I look up the component by name, create it dynamically, and give it the configuration object.

Of course, this only works if your universe of possible objects is know at compile-time, and you are just selecting and configuring them at runtime. It won't allow you to author a component and stick the source-code or the compiled object into your CMS.